# Vertical layout css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I would like to create a vertical layout with flexbox.

Here is the structure :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

And it should display 6 items per column

```
1    7
2    8
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: 6 items per column OR per row ?

Comment: Can you consider using css grid?

Comment: @GibinEalias Yes

Comment: @TemaniAfif Column ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the structure to break into a new column, it needs to know the limit to which it can fit its contents.

To make it clear, think of a simple paragraph tag with some text. Once the text exceeds the width of the page (or the container), the excess text wraps to the next line. So, in case of rows, width can be set as the limit, which is by default 100% of the viewport width or 100% of the container's width.

But here as we are dealing with columns and it takes height as the limit, the challenge here arises as the height is limitless in a HTML document. Because the height of a page increases to any extend when the content increases along with the vertical scroll bar. (Note that the same can be made possible in case of width with `overflow` a horizontal scroll bar, but here we are talking about the default behaviour).

Therefore, in this situation, to break the contents into a new column is only possible (exception with CSS grid) if we specify a height to the container.

It can either be specified in pixels or rem as mentioned in other answers.

Or if you are looking for a behaviour equivalent to the rows' as mentioned above, you can resort to `viewport-height` similar to `viewport-width` in case of rows. [PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/VQQLRb)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  height: 16.667vh;
}
```

Please note that this is not a perfect solution as it could cause misalignment when the content exceeds the height and also have browser compatibility issues. Also you may consider CSS grid or try Javascript solutions to perfectly tackle this scenario.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may upvote and/or mark the answer as correct one so that it would help other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this style:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 112px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

What I did here is set height to the container div so that the flex items wrap to the next column when it overflows. For this you need to set `flex-wrap: wrap;` too. In this case, `height: 112px` caused the overflow. You can change it as per your requirements.

Comment: 112px ? can you explain

Comment: You need to set the height of the container for the flex items to overflow to the next column. In this case, `height: 112px;` made it overflow.

Comment: which mean this will ONLY work in this particular case and this is not a generic solution

Comment: You are right. I have modified my answer and explained more.

Answer (score 0):

The height is dynamic, base on the number of items you want to control vertically (in this case 6), I have calculated the height base on a `1rem` `font-size`:

Example for 6 items:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  font-size: 1rem;
  max-height: calc(6 * 1.2em);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Example for 7 items:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  font-size: 1rem;
  max-height: calc(7 * 1.2em);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not dynamic `calc(6 * 1.125em)` as you have to change it if you change font-size and any other style so i don't see the need of complicating with calc

Comment: how do you mean? if he changes the `font-size` it will be relative to the font-size

Comment: yes only the font-size ... and if i change any other style it won't work (border, padding, margin, height, etc etc)

Comment: that's not totally true , It will only break if he uses `box-sizing: border-box` otherwise `padding`, `margin`, `border` will be applied outside the box

Comment: `box-sizing: content-box` i guess you know this is the default value ;) so he doen't need to use it and margin, border, padding will all have effect [and as side note margin has nothing to do with box-sizing]

Comment: yes, I meant `box-sizing: border-box`, with `box-sizing: content-box` it won't happen

Answer (score 0):

As the OP agreed to accept a CSS Grid solution, here is one:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
}

.child:nth-child(6n + 2) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.child:nth-child(6n + 3) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.child:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.child:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

.child:nth-child(6n) {
  grid-row-start: 6;
}
```

[PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/GQQORQ) - Hope this helps.